# How to reflect information about hlsl struct members?

Tags: reflection, shader, hlsl, directx-11

Using shader reflection in Directx 11 you can get information about individual variables by calling

```
myVar = myCbuffer->GetVariableByName/Index
```

But if the variable is a struct object, how to get info about the individual struct members?
Note that I'm not talking about the effects framework but pure hlsl and the reflection API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable's member number is stored in it's type description. Use it for iterating it's members using [GetMemberTypeByIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Example:

```
ID3D11ShaderReflectionConstantBuffer* cb = reflector->GetConstantBufferByIndex( cbIndex );
if ( cb )
{
    D3D11_SHADER_BUFFER_DESC cbDesc;
    cb->GetDesc( &cbDesc );
    if ( cbDesc.Type == D3D11_CT_CBUFFER )
    {
        for ( unsigned i = 0; i < cbDesc.Variables; ++i )
        {
            ID3D11ShaderReflectionVariable* var = cb->GetVariableByIndex( i );

            D3D11_SHADER_VARIABLE_DESC varDesc;
            var->GetDesc( &varDesc );

            ID3D11ShaderReflectionType* type = var->GetType();
            D3D11_SHADER_TYPE_DESC typeDesc;
            type->GetDesc( &typeDesc );

            for ( unsigned j = 0; j < typeDesc.Members; ++j )
            {
                ID3D11ShaderReflectionType* memberType = type->GetMemberTypeByIndex( j );
                D3D11_SHADER_TYPE_DESC memberTypeDesc;
                memberType->GetDesc( &memberTypeDesc );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok but this won't give me information about the member's name or size, which I would need.

Comment: GetMemberTypeName() returns member's name. Size can be derived from  member type description. The simplest way would be to use the Offset field.

Comment: I see. I thought it returned the type name. Good idea about the offset field.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GetMemberByName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173741%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ("If the effect variable is an structure, use this method to look up a member by name.").  If the struct has a member "foo", then...

```
myCbuffer->GetVariableByName->GetMemberByName("foo")
```

Comment: For some reason a GetMemberByName function doesn't seem to be available in the reflection API. (I've edited my question to clarify that that's what I'm talking about.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
ID3D11ShaderReflectionType::GetMemberTypeName
```

This function will returns the field member name of struct in a CBuffer.
I meet the same question when developing my HLSL reflection program. This function has been tried by myself and get correct result.