# How to reflect hlsl struct member real size in directx11?

Tags: reflection, shader, directx-11, hlsl, packing

trying to finish variable locations parser for hlsl, but can't find a way to get structure member size, in this question [How to reflect information about hlsl struct members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840765/how-to-reflect-information-about-hlsl-struct-members) it was recommended to use offset, but it won't give the actual size of member because of 16-byte packing, so if structure consists of float2 and float4 - it's total size is 32 bytes, offset of second member is 16 bytes, but real size of the first member is 8 bytes and not 16 bytes, i understand that in terms of passed memory there is 16 bytes for that variable and only 8 used, but i have "safety check" that when some value is put in stream in location of this variable - it is of the same size (in case of checking if value at least of variable size - placing it in stream can override data of next variables, and in case of checking if value is of variable size or less - it can lead to hard-to-track bugs if i forget to pass enough data for variable), so is there a way to get the real size of structure member?

Comment: I might be missing something but the struct D3D11_SHADER_VARIABLE_DESC contains the Size member? I haven't tested it but have you checked if it returns what you want?

Comment: it's for the variable only, structure description is inside of D3D11_SHADER_TYPE_DESC structure obtained from variable.GetType(), using it it's possible to get information about structure members (if type is structure, of course) in form of D3D11_SHADER_TYPE_DESC as well, so there is no straightforward info about size of anything besides the size of the whole variable